# Conditional validation in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular6, angular-validation

I want to validate the age from and age to value here.

Rules :

Age from should be less than age To.
Age To must be grater than age from

**Angular 6.0.7 version**

This is the form group defined, there are other form values also, skipped irrelevant entries here.

```
 myForm = new FormGroup({     
          'ageFrom': new FormControl( ),
          'ageTo': new FormControl(),

        });
```

This is the html search button should be disabled If the validation fails and should display an error message

```
 <input type="number"  class="form-control" formControlName="ageFrom" >        
  <input type="number"  class="form-control"  formControlName="ageTo" >
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ripple" click)="search()">Search</button>
```

Had tried custom validator, but messages are not displayed and let me know whether for this use case custom validator is required ?

**Tried**
Angular 6, below option is available

`<input min="0" max="5">`, but again they can type any number.

Comment: You need to create a custom AsyncValidator function in your controller that validates age when valueChanges observable is triggered from age inputs. If you group the inputs you want disabled, they'll be disabled when the async validation fails for the group.

Comment: Had tried custom validator: then show what you tried. That's what you need to do: a custom validator for the form group. No need for async validation of course: this validation is synchronous.

Comment: Mind formulates vague solution at first glance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template

```
<p style="color: red" *ngIf="myform.invalid">{{myform.errors | json}}</p>
<form [formGroup]="myform">
    <label>
        from:
        <input type="number" formControlName="from">
    </label>
    <label>
        to:
        <input type="number" formControlName="to">
    </label>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="myform.invalid">go</button>
</form>
```

Controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    myform = this.builder.group({
        from: '',
        to: ''
    }, {
        validator: this.isValid
    });

    constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
    }

    isValid(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
        let diff = c.value.to - c.value.from;

        return (diff < 18)
            ? { 'young': 'must be 18 years or older' }
            : null;
    }
}
```